# why QuickBlox user login is not working in android?

Tags: android, quickblox

I am using the following lines of code in an activity , it is working well for first time only, if the activity is started again the code returning neither Success nor Error

```
ChatService.getInstance().login(user, new QBEntityCallbackImpl() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Log.e("success","chat_service");
            if(getIntent().getStringExtra("mode").equals("self")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(ChatStartActivity.this, DialogsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("opponentid",getIntent().getStringExtra("opponentid"));
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }
            else{
                Intent intent = new Intent(ChatStartActivity.this, ChatActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("opponentid",getIntent().getStringExtra("opponentid"));
                intent.putExtra("mode","other");
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }
                        }

        @Override
        public void onError(List errors) {
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ChatStartActivity.this);
            dialog.setMessage("chat login errors: " + errors).create().show();
        }
    });
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You will also need to redefine the method

```
@Override
    public void onSuccess(T result, Bundle params) {
    }
```